# in blender 2.8 how to make 3d view unlike setting from other windows?

Tags: 3d-view, workspaces

in blender 2.8 how make new window witch created by [duplicated area in to new windows] unlinked setting from other windows and work space
like [viewport unlink] feature in blender 2.7
[image]

viewport unlink] feature in blender 2.7
[image: []

[viewport unlink] feature in blender 2.7